# stop a sound from playing objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[audioPlayer stop];
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Keep the Shoes Moving" ofType: @"m4a"];
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: Path];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; }
```

What happens with this is every time I navigate back to this viewController it plays another track. So then I have two tracks playing over each other. How would I get this to stop??

Answer (score 2):

Store your `AVAudioPlayer` instance in a property and call it’s `stop` method when you want it to stop playing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you please explain this further as I am a beginning coder. I know what the AVAudioPlayer is but what do you mean by calling it's stop method. Do you mean "[audioPlayer stop];"? I call that at the beginning of the viewDidLoad if that is what you mean. Should I change that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this problem? I have the same issue and `stop` is never being called as I've explained it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164873/avaudioplayer-is-always-nill-and-its-isplaying-property-is-always-false-the-fil

I'm about to declare a global variable and use it, but I'd be happy to find a better solution to this.